# MEDIA_ROOT MEDIA_URL : Rendering static server pages via Django

Tags: python, django

I have below settings in my settings.py file:

```
ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH,'site_media')
MEDIA_URL = 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:yyyy/site_media/'

And in urls.py

urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
```

And in my web page:

```
<img border="0" width="120" align="Left" src="/site_media/images/logo.gif">
```

I can see the file in the project path:

Prj/site_media/images/logo.gif

But still when I start my project in the HTML page I am not able to see the image:

```
Prj > python manage.py runserver xx.xxx.xx.xx:yyyy
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.3.1, using settings 'Prj.settings'
Development server is running at http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:yyyy/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

I am not sure what the issue is and how can I resolve it?

Below is the Request / Response headers that I see in Firebug:

```
GET http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:yyyy/site_media/images/logo.gif


Response Headers
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Thu, 12 Apr 2012 17:00:01 GMT
Server  WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.2

Request Headersview source
Accept  image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Host    xx.xxx.xx.xx:yyyy
Referer http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:yyyy/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0
```

Server logs:

```
[12/Apr/2012 09:35:11] "GET /site_media/images/logo.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 122202
```

Note even the CSS / JS scripts are also not getting loaded:

```
GET jquery-1.4.2.js

200 OK xx.xxx.xx.xx:yyyy 119.3 KB xx.xxx.xx.xx:yyyy 6.96s

HeadersResponseCache
Response Headersview source
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Thu, 12 Apr 2012 17:00:03 GMT
Server  WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.2


Request Headersview source
Accept  */*
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Host    xx.xxx.xx.xx:yyyy 
Referer http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:yyyy/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0
```

Comment: what is the server log saying when you make a request to your website? What does firebug say when you are loading your webpage?

Comment: I have added the content as seen via FireBug

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Django 1.3.1, instead of MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL, I'd suggest using django.contrib.staticfiles

Carefully read [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

in your case this would be something like:

---

settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH,'site_media')
STATIC_URL = '/site_media/'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # Your installed apps....
    # ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

# Not sure what exact context processors you need, but "static" will be one of them
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
)
```

---

To keep the admin page working, in urls.py

```
# Admin
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Admin:
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # Your other url code
)
```

---

And then on your webpage you can put:

`<img border="0" width="120" align="Left" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/logo.gif">`

Keep in mind you'll have to render your templates using the right context processors:

```
return render_to_response('my_page.html', locals(),
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```